# Create entity from 3 different mono

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor

I am new in reactive programming. I saw that two monos could be zipped to generate a result:

```
Mono<Info> info = Mono.just(id).map(this::getInfo).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

Mono<List<Detail>> detail= Mono.just(petitionRequest).map(this.service::getDetails)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel());

Flux<Generated> flux = Flux.zip(detail, info, (p, c) -> {
            Generated o = Generated.builder().info(c).detail(p).build();
            return o;
        });
```

As I have understood this paralelizes the two call and generate the object Generated when I call to `flux.blockFirst()`

How can I merge another mono to the existing two ones to generate a result? Flux.zip only accepts two monos.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, since you are zipping Monos, it would make sense to use [zip](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zip-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) operator from Mono instead of Flux.

It has multiple overloaded versions which can accept any number of Monos.

Also, if `this.service::getDetails` and `this::getInfo` are blocking IO operations (HTTP request, database call, etc.) then you should use elastic Scheduler instead of the parallel one, the latter is intended for CPU intensive operations.

Sample code:

```java
    Mono<Info> info = Mono.just(id)
                          .map(this::getInfo)
                          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

    Mono<List<Detail>> detail= Mono.just(petitionRequest)
                                   .map(this.service::getDetails)
                                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());

    Mono<Description> description = Mono.just(id)
                                        .map(this::callService)
                                        .subscribe(Schedulers.elastic());

    Mono.zip(info, detail, description)
        .map(this::map);

    private Generated map(Tuple3<Info, List<Detail>, Description> tuple3)
    {
        Info info = tuple3.getT1();
        List<Detail> details = tuple3.getT2();
        Description description = tuple3.getT3();

        // build output here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Yossarian, so Flux is only used when you want to zip Mono and Flux?

Comment: If you have publishers which could produce more than one item (e. g.: multiple Fluxes), then it could make sense to use zip from Flux. If you are dealing with Monos it's worth to keep it simple and use Mono.zip.